# Ggplot boxplot by group, change summary statistics shown

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to change the summary statistics shown in the following boxplot:

[image: boxplot]

I have created the boxplot as follows:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(beta2), aes(y=var1,x=as.factor(Year))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  ylab(expression(beta[1]))+
  xlab("\nYear")+
  theme_bw()
```

The default is for the box is the first and third quantile. I want the box to show the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles. I know one can easily change what is shown when one boxplot is visualised by adding the following to geom_boxplot:

```
aes(
    ymin= min(var1),
    lower = quantile(var1,0.025),
    middle = mean(var1),
    upper = quantile(var1,0.975),
    ymax=max(var1))
```

However, this does not work for when boxplots are generated by group. Any idea how one would do this? You can use the Iris data set:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```

EDIT:

The answer accepted does work. My data-frame is really big and as such the method provided takes a bit of time. I found another solution here: [SOLUTION](https://community.rstudio.com/t/quantile-box-plot-which-is-not-an-outlier-box-plot/24460/7) that works for large datasets and my specific need.

Comment: No, that post shows how to annotate the boxplots. I have edited my post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved via `stat_summary` by setting `geom="boxplot"`. and passing to `fun.data` a function which returns a data frame with the summary statistics you want to display as `ymin`, `lower`, ... in your boxplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "boxplot", fun.data = function(x) {
    data.frame(
      ymin = min(x),
      lower = quantile(x, 0.025),
      middle = mean(x),
      upper = quantile(x, 0.975),
      ymax = max(x) 
    )}, outlier.shape = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The dataset I am using is extremely large, 1365000 rows and applying this method seems to take a long time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hm. I just did a small benchmarking exercise using a data frame with 3m rows and compared to default `geom_boxplot`. The result is that the approach using stat_summary is slightly faster than geom_boxplot. But you are right. Rendering the plot takes some time in either case. But I'm afraid I don't know how to speed this up. ):

Comment: I have found a solution that works for me. I will edit and reference in the post.